# Какие регулярные выражения python использовать?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Прогоняю строки через регулярное выражение для обрезания, строка кода

```
k = (s[:s.find('(')] + s[s.rfind(';')] + s[s.rfind('-') + 1:-1])
```

Строка, которая у меня получается

```
{'price': '<script type="text/javascript">document.write;icon_top_2_iphone"></span>
Безопасная сделка</a> 10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽ </div>\');</script'}
```

Мне нужно вытащить из строки

```
10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽
```

Не могу допереть как дальше двигаться

Comment: А может стоить парсить `HTML` соответствующими инструментами (например `bs4`), вместо разбора регулярками?

Comment: @nomnoms12 я и парсю, но мне встретился тэг script type="text/javascript">document.write(\\\) из которого не получается достать нужный элемент, но получилось достать его весь и решил вытащить нужное мне

Comment: Приведите больше примеров входов и выходов.

Comment: @вася [Тут много таких](https://www.google.com/search?q=einfahrt+ausfahrt+image&sxsrf=ALeKk025qSlOa2HyeQ3aFDLw58IyieM2QQ:1593265100258&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibyNWCj6LqAhXV4KYKHcm8DtoQ_AUoAXoECAsQAw&biw=1745&bih=852) :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
import re, ast, html
s = r"""{'price': '<script type="text/javascript">document.write;icon_top_2_iphone"></span>Безопасная сделка</a> 10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽ </div>\');</script'}"""
d = ast.literal_eval(s)
m = re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:\xA0\d{3})*\s*₽', html.unescape(d["price"]))
if m:
    print( m.group() ) # => 10 000 ₽
```

См. [пример работы кода в Python](https://ideone.com/2oTQ3f)

`ast.literal_eval(s)` конвертирует строку в словарный объект. Нужная нам строка содержится в `d["price"]`.

`html.unescape(d["price"])` конвертирует HTML-сущности в их буквальное представление, например, `&nbsp` в неразрывный пробел.

Регулярное выражение `(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:\xA0\d{3})*\s*₽` найдёт 1-3 цифры, потом 0 и более повторов неразрывного пробела + 3 цифр, потом 0 и более пробельных символов, а затем символ `₽`, перед которыми нет другой цифры.